# application configuration for java apps in kubernetes

Tags: java, docker, configuration, kubernetes

I'm new to java and k8, and  I have some doubts about how to handle application configurations for my java apps. I've got one spring boot app and the other three use wildfly.

So, they all got hardcoded application configurations, and when starting them the just use something like:

```
java -Dswarm.project.stage=development -jar foobar/target/foobar-swarm.jar
```

except for the spring boot which has an **application.properties** file that consists of application configuration data.

So basically the three java apps have  backed in two files (which I know is a no no):

```
 - project-stages.yml
 - standalone.xml
```

And when the developer wants to deploy to production he uses:

```
  java -Dswarm.project.stage=production -jar foobar/target/foobar-swarm.jar
```

And, now we come to kubernetes which has three ways of dealing with application configuration data:

```
1.) Env variables

2.) Config maps

3.) Secrets
```

I was thinking of using **configmaps** instead of env variables because they have more [benefits](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-configmaps-and-secrets-68d061f7ab5b).

So, the developer gave me the possibility of overwriting those hardcoded variables with an external file : **Dsystem.properties.file=/var/foobar/environment.properties**

But I'm still overwriting an hardcoded files with an external file, and I'm not happy with that solution!

So, I'm basically looking on advise can those hardcoded files be supplied externally and populated with configmaps in k8 - what would be the best practice of handling the config files in the world of k8?

Tnx,
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several questions in the post, but I can address only the one related to spring-boot.

The simplest and the most convenient way of specifying configurations to spring boot app is via its built in profiling feature. As you already mentioned you have `application.properties`. You can create similar files according to your usage cases: `application-production.properties`, `application-staging.properties`, `application-k8s.properties`, etc. 
Kubernetes deployment doesn't change this in any way.
You can control which configuration to pick by setting `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` env variable from the kubernetes.

You might have something like this:

```
docker run -e SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=k8s -d -p 0.0.0.0:8080:8080 \
    --name=yourapp your_image_name bash -c "java -jar yourapp.jar"
```

It will pick configuration from `application-k8s.properties`.

Configuration files support environment variables as well.
You can have placeholders like `${YOUR_DB}` in your properties files and Spring will automatically pick up env variable with name `YOUR_DB`. It is convenient to use this feature let's say when your app pod must have its own db pod.

Comment: in this soln you have to pre-package your application file `application-k8s.properties` with docker image right? that means now you have docker image for different env?

Comment: @nir I am not sure what you mean. There is no need to operate with images on the application level. You need to refer containers in your application (instances of images). You refer them by aliases in your `application-k8s.properties` and the aliases come from your deployment. You can also inject them via environment variables like I explained in the answer.

Comment: May be i'm missing something with your suggestion but Hubert Ströbitzer answer made sense to me. Your spring-boot (or standalone java) app is starting inside a container and it needs a property file (application-whatever.properties) to load. So either you have to pre-package that property file or mount the configmap as Hubert suggested or have some other external service provides that to spring-boot

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question right you are asking how to configure a Spring Boot application via a k8s ConfigMap. Yes, you can do that.

1. Create a Docker image with WORKDIR work_dir in which you start the Spring Boot application eg via java -jar /work_dir/app.jar
2. Create a ConfigMap
3. Run a container of the above mentioned image within k8s
4. Mount the ConfigMap for the Spring Boot application.properties into the Container as /work_dir/config/application.properties
5. On changes in the ConfigMap the file within the container gets updated. You have to restart the Spring Boot Application to set your changes active.